# Images and Audio in an Alert Dialog

Tags: java, android, image, google-maps, audio

I'm using the following tutorial  http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html in order to create a map view and plot points on to it. I have all of that done fine but now I'd like to embed an image and even audio within the Alert dialogs that pop up. Is this possible in the current context? How would I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a [Custom Dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog).